# Downgrade from Spike 3 Hub OS to Spike 2 Hub OS

Tags: software, spike-prime

**I'm trying to downgrade our Spike Prime Hub from the [Spike App v3](https://spike.legoeducation.com/)'s firmware to the [Spike App v2](https://spikelegacy.legoeducation.com/)'s firmware.** Has anyone been successful? Or does anyone have suggestions on how to flash the firmware to a version that's compatible with Spike App v2.0.8  or v2.0.9?

##### Context

I upgraded our hub to Spike 3. This is the default recommended behavior through the new v3 app as of December 1st, 2022, as follows.

> **DO NOT DO THESE STEPS IF YOU NEED YOUR v2 CODE TO WORK WITH YOUR SPIKE PRIME HUB**
>
> Navigate to Spike App v3 (link above) and notice that there is a new version of the app
>
> Select Prime
>
> Click Update Hub on the popup
>
> Follow the steps to update the firmware for the v3 Spike App

After doing so, I realized our existing v2 Spike Prime code would no longer be compatible. There's a different filename extension for the new files (`.llsp3` vs `.llsp`). Eventually, I want to switch to the newer app, but for now, I am trying to get our .llsp code working again.

##### Attempted resolution

- As suggested at [this support page](https://education.lego.com/en-us/teacher-resources/lego-education-spike-prime/start-here/lego-education-spike-prime-the-lego-education-spiketm-app) (screenshot below) and via built-in troubleshooting steps in the app, I went to https://spike.legoeducation.com/hubdowngrade to downgrade.

> [image]

- Because I know v2 of the app is available at a similar URL (starting with `spikelegacy` instead of `spike`), I attempted using the tool at https://spikelegacy.legoeducation.com/hubdowngrade/.

Comment: There's some hope via: 1. https://dfu.pybricks.com/index.html 2. https://github.com/gpdaniels/spike-prime/tree/master/firmware/spike%20-%20v1.3.00.0000-e8c274a%20-%204.0.0 3. https://spikelegacy.legoeducation.com/hubdowngrade/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha!

1. *Prerequisite for Windows:* Use [this tool](https://zadig.akeo.ie/) to install a driver. (See tips [here](https://dfu.pybricks.com/extra.html).)
2. Use the https://spikelegacy.legoeducation.com/hubdowngrade/ downgrade tool.
3. Go back to https://spikelegacy.legoeducation.com/ to reconnect.
4. Follow the prompts to update the Hub OS one last time.